# html to "pdf" text background goes to a new line but the text itself doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

Here is the html opened in the browser

```css
div {
  width: 480px;
}

ul.skills {
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.skills li {
  display: inline-block;
  /* transform: translate(-50%,-50%); */
  padding: 3px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #b9c5ce;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #657180;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h5>
    Skill-եր
  </h5>
  <ul class="skills">
    <li>Angular</li>
    <li>Angular JS</li>
    <li>Bootstrap</li>
    <li>C#</li>
    <li>CakePHP</li>
    <li>Java</li>
    <li>JavaScript</li>
    <li>PHP</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

here is the result after converting it to pdf

[image]

note: pdf doesn't support display flex and table cell so...

Comment: That can't be your full CSS: There is no background-color setting in your CSS rules. So maybe there is also something else missing that might be the key to the problem.

Comment: no no the only difference is the `background-color:yellow;` that's all

Comment: and only `body` around it?